# Is there any benefit to aligning the *end* of the last partition on an SSD?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I created two partitions with KDE's partition manager that fully filled an SSD, and noticed that there were 3MB unallocated at the end. Turns out the partitioning tool had automatically aligned the partition. I understand the benefits of aligning the *start* of the partition, but since this is the last partition, what is the benefit of leaving unallocated space too small to create another partition in?